# D3 two donut charts on top of one another, different data sets. Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

What I'm trying to do is make two charts display in the same field, one to show the time spent working vs. the time spent idling, and the other chart to show whether the machine is currently working or idling.

I want the chart that shows the machine idling to be smaller than the first and fit inside it.  I've been able to make both charts but I am unable to combine them in the way that I want them to.

[[what I have right now]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZofRI.png)

[[what I'd like to do]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoV1e.png)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <div id="chart-center-jc1" align="center"></div>
 <!--this line control location of the SVG chart-->



<script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var radius = 80,
padding = 10;
var radius2 = 25,
padding = 10;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range([ "#fc0303", "#21d525", "#d0cece", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius)
.innerRadius(radius - 30);

var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius2)
.innerRadius(radius2 - 25);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var pie2 = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return d.population; });

d3.csv("M1 Summary.csv", function(error, data) {
 if (error) throw error;

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !=="Machine"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {name: name, population: +d[name]};
    });
  });

  var legend = d3.select("#chart-center-jc1").append("svg")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 2)
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

   legend.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

   legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });

  var svg = d3.select("#chart-center-jc1").selectAll(".pie")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("class", "pie2")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 3)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");


  svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(function(d) { return pie(d.ages); })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "arc")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });


  svg.selectAll(".arc2")
  .data(function(d) { return pie2(d.ages); })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "arc2")
  .attr("d", arc2)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to append one svg onto another:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart-center-jc1").append("svg")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 3)
  .attr("class","outerPie")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var svg2 = d3.select(".outerPie").append("svg")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 3)
  .attr("class","innerPie")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
```

Note that both svgs have the same height, width, and translate.  This is because they are on top of one another, and you want to position the second in the center of the first.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv6to6f2/3/) for complete solution.